# HistoricalScheduler in Rx

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have following code where I try to replay sequence; but PostWorkItem always gets null; I don't understand why. ***Below code give Stack overflow error.***

```
        Task<List<WorkItem>> WorkItems = DbUtil.GetWorkItems(new List<string>() { WorkItemStatus.NEW, WorkItemStatus.PROCESSING });
         Items = WorkItems.Result;

        replay = Observable.Generate(
                Items.GetEnumerator(),
                events => events.MoveNext(),
                events => events,
                events => events.Current,
                events => System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
                    var);

        replay.Subscribe(
            W => 
                PostWorkItem(W)
            );

        //var.AdvanceBy(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        var.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the type parameters in `Observable.Generate` explicitly so that it doesn't get confused with the non-generic IEnumerator. Try replacing your third line of code with:

```
replay = Observable.Generate<IEnumerator<WorkItem>,WorkItem>(
```

Comment: James  Thanks; code worked after your suggestions; but when I use Scheduler.AdvanceTo(Date.Now) then this creates StackOverFlow error.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that `Observable.Generate` is not recursive, so I'm pretty certain it's going to be down to the enumerator you are using. I suggest you set up some break points and examine the stack and see what's on it and how its growing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. By commenting out this code it does not throW stack overflow . //events => events.Current.RequestedDateTime, But I wanted to AdvanceTo untill 12th Feb. I cannot do that...I want to make sure that AdvanceTo relates to RequesteDateTime of all itemsso I can replay only untill 12th Feb and then in next iteration I will AdvanceTo 14th Feb...